# Vim how to remove some words using regex

Tags: regex, vim

In vim editor, I want to delete parentheses and the words in parentheses using regular expression.

Help me please!

As-is:

```
DOT("."), COMMA(","), SEMICOLON(";"), COLON(":"), QUOTE("'"),
EQUALS("="), NOT_EQUALS("<>"), LESS_THAN("<"), LESS_EQUALS("<="),
```

Want To-be:

```
DOT, COMMA, SEMICOLON, COLON, QUOTE,
EQUALS, NOT_EQUALS, LESS_THAN, LESS_EQUALS,
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really take the time to learn regex properly, it's fairly useful and pretty cool stuff. That being said, this is a good time to learn at least this part.

You have a text list and you want to match everything that isn't within parentheses, repeatedly over a line.

```
%s/\([^(]*\)[^)]*)\([^(]*\)/\1\2/g
```

First, we're gonna do this over the whole file, so let's use `%s`. Next, we have `/` as our separator. Our pattern that we'll match is therefore `\([^(]*\)[^)]*)\([^(]*\)`.

Let's break that down some more. `\( \)` is the grouping operator, which just tells vim "hey, I might want the stuff in here later." `[^ ]` is the not operator, and says "I a character that isn't any of these characters". `[^)]*` then says "I want all the characters I can grab in a row that aren't ")". All of that was group one.

After our first `\( \)` we have stuff that isn't in a group, because we don't want to keep it. `[^)]*)` uses the not operator again, to match a bunch of characters that aren't ")", and then we have a ")", which matches a literal ")" (there's probably a better way to do this part, but it works.

Next, we have our second `\( \)` group which contains `[^(]*`. Again, another not operator, matching as many non "(" in a row as we can. We need our pattern to stop by the next "(" so that our regex can match multiple times on the line; if we'd used `\(.*\)` instead, we'd have to run our regex a bunch of times since we'd only remove one set of parens per run.

After our pattern, we have another `/` which delimits the pattern what we're going to put in it's place. Remember how I said `\( \)` tells vim to keep the stuff inside for later? Here's where we use it. Our first group is basically "everything before a (" and our second group is basically "everything after a )". We tell vim we want to just keep group 1 followed by group 2 with `\1\2`.

Finally, `/g` means do to our regex globally over the line, meaning to try matching more than once in the line if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short one:

```
%s/(.\{-})//g
```

Explanations: it matches a parenthese `(`, then as few characters as possible `.\{-}` before the next closing parenthese `)`. It replaces this whole match by nothing.

Answer (score 2):

To keep it simple  without having a too much strict regex, I would use

```
:%s#("..\?")##g
```

This will basically remove any character or two within double quotes and parenthesis.

Is using also `#` instead of `/` it may be easy to read and in some cases helps to avoid escaping `/` when required.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this pattern:**

```
(?:[A-Z]{3,9}|, |_){1,2}
```

You can test it [online](https://www.regextester.com/94653)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
%s/("[.,;:'=<][>=]*")//g
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the solutions already given are excellent. Like some of the others, I'd recommend learning how to regex in more depth. For your specific issue, you could alternatively search for opening brackets with `/(` then use `da)` to delete the brackets and their contents (skip if you want to keep this particular pair), move to the next match with `n`, repeat the deletion with `;`, and do this until you've deleted what you need.